# Laravel Dynamic Application Deployment in Heroku Not Working

Tags: laravel, heroku, error-handling, deployment

I have hosted my Laravel website in Heroku platform for test
website : https://ipd-kiu.herokuapp.com/

I have built a login system here  for an institute

https://ipd-kiu.herokuapp.com/login

When I try to log in via login form, I found an error

> The information you’re about to submit is not secure Because this form
> is being submitted using a connection that’s not secure, your
> information will be visible to others.
>
> 419 PAGE EXPIRED

Please help me to fix the issue .

Login code form is below:

```html
<form action="http://ipd-kiu.herokuapp.com/loginprocess" method="POST">
    
    
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="email_address" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">E-Mail Address</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input  type="text" id="email_address" class="form-control" name="email"  required >
                    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>
                    </div>
    </div>

    

    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            Login
        </button>
    </div> --}}

</form>
```

Comment: You're missing a CSRF Token for your `method="POST"` form. Please check the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/csrf

Comment: i have tried by adding @CSRF but after submitting the data it again shows  419 error i will update the project in 10 mints by adding CSRF you can check it .

Comment: If you have any kind of view caching (which you generally do on production), you'll need to update that for the `@CSFR` token to be included.

Comment: Check the code i have added  but it   will not show when we inspect in google to check it.       {{-- @csrf --}}
    {{-- <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"> --}}

Comment: `<form method="POST">@csrf</form>` will render as `<form method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="_token" value="..."/></form>`. If you use `{{-- @csrf --}}`, then nothing will render, as those are `.blade` templating Comments... Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73802233/edit) with the actual code you're using. There _are_ other ways to get a `419` error, but the main one is if you don't have a csrf token.

Comment: i have deployed it in heruko thourough cli and the database is postgress  but my local project was in mysql i think this will not cause any problem ... i think the problem is with my login process controller .    if you want to check i will share the code here .

Comment: If you use {{-- @csrf --}}, then nothing will render, yea let me to change and deploy it again  i hope i will work .

Comment: Yes, literally type the 5 characters `@csfr` after `<form action="http://ipd-kiu.herokuapp.com/loginprocess" method="POST">` and it _should_ work (pending any other session-related issues)

Comment: <form action="{{ route('loginprocess') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf   thanks for your time .. wait i will push the project again to heruko so that you can also check the reflects

Comment: remote:  Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/ipd-kiu.git
   968327b..efeab35  master -> master
branch 'master' set up to track 'heroku/master'.